# In Spyder, is there some way to plot a dataframe by right-clicking it like you can with arrays?

Tags: ipython, spyder

I've just recently discovered that you can right-click an array in [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) and get a quick plot of the data. With sample data like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Some numbers in a data frame
nsample = 440
x1 = np.linspace(0, 100, nsample)
y = np.sin(x1)
dates = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2016, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=nsample).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'x1':x1, 'y':y})
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

you can go to the Variable explorer, right-click y and get the following directly in the console:

[image]

which will give you this:

[image]

The same option does not seem to be available to a pandas dataframe:

[image]

Sure, you could easily go for `df.plot()`:

[image]

But I really like the right-click option to check whether the variables and dataframes look the way I expect them to when I'm messing around with a lot of data. So, is there any library I'd have to import? Or maybe something in the settings? I've also noticed that what happens in the console is this little piece of magic: `%varexp --plot y`, but can't seem to find an equivalent for data frames.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is just a bit of missing functionality for Dataframes, but it's very easy to implement.

Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), so we don't forget to do it in a future release.

Comment: I'll do that, and thank you for your swift response.

Comment: Would you please add a pointer to the relevant issue, so that others can track progress?  This answer is old, and this feature is one I very much would like.

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman, I think no one opened an issue for it. Please open one if you care about this being addressed in the future.

Comment: Since I stumbled upon this and I definitively care, I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13583).